# FileTime to string

Tags: java, c#, windows, filetime

I'm reading some Microsoft FileTime values, stored as a long, and I'm trying to convert it into a human readable date.

For instance, the value `131733712713359180` converts to: `Wednesday, June 13, 2018 1:47:51pm`.  This was done using the online tool, here: [Online time convertor](http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=131733712713359180&inputformat=filetime)

I've got it working in Java fine, but when I try to do it in C#, I'm getting the wrong year.  The output I get is: `13/06/0418 13:47:51`.

The code I'm using to do the conversion is:

```
public string CalculateTimestamp(Int64 epoch)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

    try
    {
        date = new DateTime(epoch);
        DateTime filetime = new DateTime(date.ToFileTime());
        result = filetime.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception uhoh)
    {
        result = "failedtoparsetimestamp";
    }

    return result;
}
```

When doing the conversion in Java, this is the code I'm using.

```
public String calculateTimeStamp(long epoch) {

    if (epoch == 0) {
        return "--";
    }

    long unixDifference = 11644473600000L;

    long timeStamp = (epoch / (10 * 1000)) - unixDifference;

    Date date = new Date(timeStamp);

    return date.toString();
}
```

I guessed that the C# conversion should be more straight forward, but I can't figure out why the year is wrong.  I've tried both `UInt64` and `Int64`, both give the same (wrong) result.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just do `var date = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(131733712713359180);`, which returns `2018-06-13 13:47:51`

Comment: @MatthewWatson You ought to make that an answer...

Comment: Your Java code is using terrible legacy date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. For .Net platform, use a library similar to *java.time* called [*NodaTime*](https://nodatime.org/), based on the predecessor to *java.time* called *Joda-Time* ported from Java to C#.

Comment: Yeah, that code has been in place for years now, and I hadn't looked at it until yesterday. I'll get it updated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is built-in to `DateTime` so there's no need to do any adjustments:

```
var date = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(131733712713359180);
```

This returns `2018-06-13 13:47:51`

Comment: Yup, that got it!  I can't believe I didn't see that, I was staring at it for over ten minutes.  Thank you :)